# How far from the head is the skin overlay?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm in a map making team and I have to make the NPC model. We decided to have the proportions roughly the same, but I don't know how many pixels are in between the head's overlay and the head itself on the default player skin model. What are the number of pixels between the head overlay and the actual head?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a model is something vectorial, there's is no number of pixels that would answer the question. (Since a pixel is a 2D matricial value and a model is a 3D vectorial element) To measure the exact distance would require a 3D editor software (and that value would be relative to the rest of the scaling of the character.)

On the other hand, you can see [here](https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_400_400/p/5/005/09b/324/33b844e.png) that it's somewhat close to half a pixel of the texure that you apply on the characters. So this is possibly as precise as you can get by eye without requiring to dive into proportions and a 3D editor.

[image]